# "Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided" When trying to do Server Side Rendering in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ejs, server-side-rendering

Hi I'm trying to do server-side rendering in my react app but I get the error

> Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.

I've got an ejs template index.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Hello Redux</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/cyborg/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-D9XILkoivXN+bcvB2kSOowkIvIcBbNdoDQvfBNsxYAIieZbx8/SI4NeUvrRGCpDi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"><%- myHtml -%></div>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

A request handler function:

```
'use strict'

import axios from 'axios'

function handleRender(req, res){
  axios.get('http://localhost:3001/books')
    .then(function(response){
      var myHtml = JSON.stringify(response.data);
      res.render('index', { myHtml })
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      console.log('#Initial Server-side rendering error', err);
    })
}

module.exports = handleRender;
```

And in app.js I require the request handler function and set it:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(requestHandler);
```

Can anyone help me with this issue? The link to my github repo with all the code is at https://github.com/edward-hong/book-shop

Answer (score 0):

in app.js

```
var app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));

var apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
  target: 'http://localhost:3001'
});

app.use('/api', function(req, res){
  apiProxy.web(req,res)
})

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

just move `app.set('view engine', 'ejs')` and put it right after `var app = express()`

Comment: Hi taha, I'm getting the same error after rearranging that line of code

Answer (score 0):

apiServer.js is your entry, so you need to explicitly `app.set('view engine', 'ejs')` there

Comment: Hi taha, it's still not working. Currently I have `app.set('view engine', 'ejs')` right after `var app = express()` in both app.js and apiServer.js

Comment: what I'm trying to say is that you have to set the view engine before anything that might need to use it